# Progress update message for multiple processes in multiple tabs using SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have a web-scraping project where extracting content from sites can take more than a minute (sometimes even more). So I implemented a progress-update module using SignalR to display, for example, “Day 1 of 14 | Getting line item 23,” so users know the process is still ongoing.

The user selects a 3-letter code from the intended country and presses the EXTRACT button. Upon clicking the EXTRACT button, my SignalR status update begins transmitting the status update (see Screenshot 1).

**Screenshots**
[image]

Now, a user may choose to open a new tab and process another job. When I do that, the process in Tab 1 stops (i.e., the status update becomes static, staying at “6IH | Day 5 of 7 | Getting line item 147”) (see Tab 1 screenshot) and the process status update from Tab 1 continues to get displayed in Tab 2 along with the Tab 2 process status update (in fact, these 2 process update messages appear alternatively). Unfortunately, I am unable to take a screenshot of that scenario; however, see Tab 2 screenshot where the Tab 1 process-complete message is displayed, whereas Tab 2 process is actually in progress (as seen by the “in process” chrome display).

My JavaScript is here. I create a unique ID every time a user clicks the “EXTRACT” button (hoping to create a unique instance). I pass the unique value to the aspx page and initiate the `createJobID(jobIdVar)` function to add the job ID to the SignalR group `Groups.Add(myConnectionId, jobID);`

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {
                    var jobIdVar = guid();
                    //$.connection.hub.logging = true;
                    var hubProxy = $.connection.myHub;
                    hubProxy.client.jobCompleted = function (message) {
                        $('#signalr_french_status').text(message.toString());
                        console.log(message);
                        $.connection.hub.stop();
                        jobIdVar = null;
                        console.log('SignalR connection closed!');
                        window.location.reload(true);
                        console.log('Page refreshed');
                    }
                    hubProxy.client.setStatus = function (message) {
                        $('#signalr_french_status').text(message.toString());
                        console.log(message);
                        console.log('Sent message! Job ID: ' + jobIdVar);
                    }
                    $.connection.hub.start()
                        .done(function () {
                            console.log('Connected to hub: ' + $.connection.hub.id);
                        })
                    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
                        $.connection.hub.start();
                    })
                    $('#master_template_page_pandora_french_panel_extract_button').click(function () {
                        //alert('clicked');
                        var url = '/main/asdf.aspx';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { 'job_id': jobIdVar },
                            success: function (html) {
                                hubProxy.server.createJobID(jobIdVar);
                                console.log('CreateJobID done: Added to the group! Job ID: ' + jobIdVar);
                            },
                        });
                    })
                    function guid() {
                        function s4() {
                            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                              .toString(16)
                              .substring(1);
                        }
                        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
                          s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
                    }
                })()
            </script>
```

My hub methods are here:

```
public string myStatus;
public static string myConnectionId;
public void SetCurrentStatus(string jobID)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PandoraStatus>();
    context.Clients.Group(jobID).setStatus(myStatus);
}
public void CreateJobID(string jobID)
{
    Groups.Add(myConnectionId, jobID);
}
public void JobCompleted(string jobID)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PandoraStatus>();
    context.Clients.Group(jobID).jobCompleted(myStatus);
}
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
{
    myConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

My progress-update implementation is here.

```
    MyHub status = new MyHub();
    try
    {
        extractStatus = "AN2 | Day " + dayToBeExtracted + " of 14 | Getting line item " + lineItem;
        status.myStatus = extractStatus;
        status.SetCurrentStatus(jobIDForProcessing);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        status.myStatus = "AN2 | Error! Check log!";
        status.JobCompleted(jobIDForProcessing);
    }
    finally
    {
        status.myStatus = "AN2 | Process complete!";
        status.JobCompleted(jobIDForProcessing);
    }
```

I need to know how I can display unique messages in each tab.